# C# Crop then scale the Cropped Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

I'm trying to build this class (to use in ASP.NET site) that will Crop Image given custom Width,Height X,Y, then take the result image and Scale it to Custom Width, Height, And save in directory on the server return url of this image.

And i will get these paramerts in querystring like this

```
Default.aspx?x=100&y=300&w=800&h=500&scalew=160&scaleh=100
```

So this is what i got so far

```
    public static Image CustomCrop(int width, int height, int x, int y, int scalwidth, int scalheight)
    {
        try
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile("Images/none.jpg");
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            bmp.SetResolution(80, 60);

            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gfx.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), x, y, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


            return bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I will send these values Crop Image (width, height, x, y) then Scale the Croped image (scalwidth, scalheight) then save jpg in directory and return url for the image location

So what is the best way to this?

Comment: Someone voted this question down, without explaining why. Come on people... don't do that. If the motivation for downvote is not in the comments, please post a comment on **why do you think this is wrong**... I don't find this question should be downvoted, instead I answered it. Not everybody knows everything. The question author did show effort in solving his own question, he had almost half of it already... what's wrong with people here is SO.

Comment: Almost 5 years later I am still asking same question to myself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Generic Handler` (i.e. ashx file) in your asp.net website or application, and place the following code inside it. Call it for example "Handler.ashx".

Now, in the browser use: `Handler.ashx?x=100&y=300&w=800&h=500&scalew=160&scaleh=100`

Code of **Handler.ashx** file:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        int x = int.Parse(context.Request["x"]);
        int y = int.Parse(context.Request["y"]);
        int h = int.Parse(context.Request["h"]);
        int w = int.Parse(context.Request["w"]);
        int scalew = int.Parse(context.Request["scalew"]);
        int scaleh = int.Parse(context.Request["scaleh"]);
        using (Image img = CustomCrop(w, h, x, y, scalew, scaleh))
            img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream,ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
    }

    public static Image CustomCrop(int width, int height, int x, int y, int scalwidth, int scalheight)
    {
        try
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile("c:\\x.jpg");
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(scalwidth, scalheight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            bmp.SetResolution(80, 60);

            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gfx.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, scalwidth, scalheight), x, y, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


            return bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Some reference about Generic Handlers:

[HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx)

[@ WebHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366713.aspx) - how ashx files work.

Comment: It does work great as i wanted it, But seems there r some performance issues image very big. so i will try to enhance is, Thank you

Comment: Well, it should - it leaks memory like a sieve. Every System.Drawing object has to be wrapped in a using(){} clause. Also, this will cause a 50% transparent border around the outer edge.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already have working code which is indeed one of the way - you can perhaps add compression (for example, JPEG format would use lossy compression) - see this article: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/image-resizing-cropping-and-compression.html

However, **I will recommend not to use `System.Drawing` namespace**. As per [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx), using GDI+ (that's System.Drawing) in ASP.NET applications is not supported. Rather, it recommends Windows Imaging Components (i.e. **use [WPF Imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx)** from .NET perspective - it uses WIC internally). See this article that will start you using WPF for cropping/scaling images: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/12/10/resizing-images-from-the-server-using-wpf-wic-instead-of-gdi.aspx

Comment: Ok seems to me there r many components written using the System.Drawing but yet its not supported and it cause runtime error in some cases, i will try WPF Imaging and test both of them

Answer (score 1):

A [well tested and proven open-source library already exists for this - imageresizing.net](http://imageresizing.net), which supports both GDI+, WIC, and FreeImage backends. I wrote it in 2009, and have released 60 new versions since then. It's used on over 10,000 websites, and powers some extremely large social networking sites.

System.Drawing is *nearly* impossible to use correctly. [I've documented about 30 pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/), and more are soon to follow. It's possible to do it safely, but you're not going to do it by copying and pasting code.

It's better to use a wrapper than handles memory management for you from end-to-end, and avoids all the GDI+ and ASP.NET pitfalls.