# C# crop, scale, rotate image

Tags: javascript, c#, image

I use a javascript client plugin for manipulate image inside the browser (JQuery Guillotine). After I will want manipulate the image with the server but I don't know which library can help me for do this job.

When I call the server I send these information:

```
{ scale: 1.4, angle: 270, x: 10, y: 20, w: 400, h: 300 }
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381310/c-sharp-crop-then-scale-the-cropped-image?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the [AForge.net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) imaging library. I've used it before and found it easy to implement, reliable and quick. It does everything, but you may find that it's overkill for what you need.

I used it in a kinect project that needed to measure the distance between a person's pupils. After finding the eye with the kinect I used this library to cut out the image of the eye, then apply several filters (and some other imaging magic) to pinpoint the center of the each pupil. This was occurring at about 30fps and this image processor (on a fairly decent machine) kept up with the demand and didn't miss a beat.

Or, seeing as you're just resizing, cropping and rotating, you could just use the System.Drawing libraries already built in to .net

Here are a few examples to get you started: http://dotnet-snippets.com/snippet/crop-and-resize-images/676

Comment: thank you! I start with .NET Image Library. But i don't know how use the parameter scale: 1.4 (when I zoom image and then I apply crop).

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several libraries available to do this, but I have a good experience with implementing this one: http://imageprocessor.org/.

Comment: can you provide some sample code?

Comment: View their website for usage instructions. It's basically as simple as installing a NuGet package.